# what is the best way to create a release apk for the expo app made with custom dev client

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I've built an app with expo managed workflow but then we needed a native module to be added to the app so I generated native project files using `expo run:[android | ios]` which works well on the development but I'm curious what could be the best approach to generate android release apk for the current project?

If I follow the `expo build:[android | ios]` I think my native changes won't be included in that build. But at the same time if I use `gradlew assembleRelease` then I think I will lose the expo OTA updates.

Sorry if my question seems a mess but I really need some guidance following that approach.:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at Expo EAS  - https://docs.expo.dev/build/introduction/